# How to achive javascript functionality if javascript disabled from browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have Create a ASP.NET MVC Project.and in this project i have used javascript much more.like JQGRID,FullCalender etc.and everything is working fine.
                                                                  Now a Tester Disabled Javascript from Browser and now nothing is working,no jqGrid ,no full Calender etc(JavaScript Functionalty).Now Please suggest how can i achive my javascript functionality.
                                                                              Any Help will be Appreciated.

Comment: you can' do anything... except to use [noscript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) to warn the user that the site required javascript.... or create a non javascript version in `noscript`...

Comment: Its impossible. refer http://www.enable-javascript.com/ for intimating user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Once javascript is disabled in the browser there is nothing that can be done by the developer of the website to re-enable it.

You need to 'code defensively' (also known in the case of javascript as 'progressive enhancement'), by having a backup system in place which allows the user with javascript disabled to still browse the site. For example, with javascript enabled the user can page between tabular data, with it disabled they see all data in a single page.

Alternatively, you should add an advisory warning to the entry page of your site which detects if javascript is disabled and advises people that for full use of your site it is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use javascript if the browser does not allow you to. But you could try to substitute some things by using CSS3 (For instance, animations, transitions, etc.).